# ordering a list of names based upon related values, accounting for duplicate values, excel

Tags: excel, list

I have a sheet that pulls metrics regarding employees from an internal source, I am trying to create an end of day report card and would like to display the names in ranking order based upon the metrics.

a small example for demonstration:

[image]

Columns A and B:  An example of the kind of data in my sheet.

column D:         I have used a variation of

```
=INDEX(A$2:A$6,MATCH(E2,B$2:B$6,0))
```

Column E:

```
=LARGE(B$2:B$6,1)
```

as you can see, I am running into trouble with duplicate 'total' values creating an incorrect index number causing the first name that matches to be the result.

column G i have attempted to get around this by using:

```
=INDEX(A$16:A$20,MATCH(E19,B$16:B$20,0)+COUNTIF(B$16:B$20,E19)-1)
```

to attempt to account for the duplicates by adding a countif to the index number, of course, is an incorrect approach.

Not shown I also tried adding 0.5/'employee id number' to the total (0.5/an integer gives me a decimal between 0 and 0.5 allowing me to have each number be unique without causing any rounding problems to the displayed total. However, *I think* the decimal was ignored by the MATCH and it made no effect.

A weird problem has had me puzzled and I appreciate any help!

Comment: Have you considered using SORT? (ex. `=SORT(A2:B6,2,1,FALSE)`)

Comment: I cant try this at home as I don't have the function, will see if it's on the version instaled on my work computer.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like this

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$6,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW($A$2)+1)/($E2=$B$2:$B$6),COUNTIF($E$2:E2,E2)))

=INDEX($A$9:$A$13,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$9:$A$13)-ROW($A$9)+1)/($E9=$B$9:$B$13),COUNTIF($E$9:E9,E9)))

=INDEX($A$16:$A$20,AGGREGATE(15,6,(ROW($A$16:$A$20)-ROW($A$16)+1)/($E16=$B$16:$B$20),COUNTIF($E$16:E16,E16)))
```

[image: Formula required to extract User for duplicate metric]

Comment: And with respect to the solution provided by @cybernetic.nomad then it should be in descending order since you need the largest value therefore it should be like this, although you need to have O365 for using this formula =SORT(A2:B6,2,-1,FALSE)

Comment: this is great, I appreciate it.
I'm just taking a second to work out exactly what is going on here. I have never seen aggregate before.

Comment: @AshleyReid thank you madam, you can clearly refer the image i have attached, it works as per your expectation, also note AGGREGATE Function is available to all users from Excel 2010 till O365, however i am not sure which version of excel you are using, still Excel 2007 doesnt supports it, and then you can use the SMALL Function in place of that then the formula will be =INDEX($A$2:$A$6,SMALL(IF($E2=$B$2:$B$6,ROW($A$2:$A$6)-ROW($A$2)+1),COUNTIF($E$2:E2,E2))) and confirm press with CTRL SHIFT ENTER since its an array formula ! I hope this helps, thanks a million!